# Play Framework 2.2.1: Timeout for Asynchronous Request

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, timeout

I am trying to get the content/body of a http request. This already works, but I can't get the timeout with the `get` method to work.

```
    Logger.info( "before WS.url" );
    String res = WS.url( "http://1.2.3.4" ).get()
        .map( new Function<WS.Response, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(WS.Response response) throws Throwable {
                return response.getBody();
            }
        } )
        .get( 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
    Logger.info( "after WS.url = " + res );

    return res;
```

In my code the timeout just doesn't work, what am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Firstly, you should never call .get on a promise in a Play application, you should return a mapped promise to your action, calling .get could get you in all sorts of trouble like deadlocks.  Aside from that, what do you mean the timeout method with the get doesn't work? What's happening?

Comment: I never get a TimeoutException, although I set a timeout. I fixed this by using Scala and `Await.result`.

Comment: `Await.result` is never the right answer, you are likely to end up with deadlocks or worse in production if you use it.  You should always `map` or `flatMap` futures, and return asynchronous results from actions.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?